# How to define inheritance type in hibernate if you can't modify de parent class

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

The issue is this, I'm extending a generic framework and applying it to an specific proyect, the framework works with Spring and Hibernate, here I have two classes, **GenericClient** and **SpecificClient**, they are both entities, and **SpecificClient** inherits from **GenericClient**.

**GenericClient** is part from the framework and I can't modify it, since this class doesn't declares `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` the only type of inheritance type that can be used is `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` because this is the default value of the annotation.

Currently my code is working with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` being declared in **SpecificClient**, even though it is not the root of the inheritance tree.

Due to version issues I have to find the way to use `InheritanceType.JOINED`, the good thing is that **SpecificClient** will always be the last class of the inheritance tree, but can be different in different projects.

- Is there any way in that I can inject the annotation `InheritanceType.JOINED` in the parent class?
- Is there any way that the parent class can be declared in such a way that according to the needs of specific projects you can use one kind of inheritance of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XML to define the mapping of this inheritance tree. Here's the [relevant section of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#inheritance-tablepersubclass).

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify a class that you want Hiberante to use as an Entity, you may use the .hbm.xml configuration files to do so.  These can be mixed with the annotations as all features should be available in both.